# SMTP 25 closed even though I allow everything in firewall (Debian server running sendmail)

Tags: firewall, smtp, sendmail

I am running sendmail + dovecot in my Debian server. I have enabled the firewall rules to allow everything:

```
  iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
  iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
  iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
  iptables -F
  iptables -X
```

However after a quick check at yougetsignal.com, my port 25 is still being blocked. But 143, 80 are okay.

Comment: Short answer: Your ISP blocks the port. But this is a question for SuperUser, not ServerFault.

Comment: @pehrs you sure about that? The answer seems to have got it working (see OP's comment on the answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, with thanks to symcbean, check it's running.  On the system itself, type

```
telnet localhost 25
```

and if you don't see something like

```
220 risby.home.domainname.net ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.2; Wed, 1 Dec 2010 10:20:38 GMT
```

your sendmail isn't running in daemon mode, and you won't be able to get to it from anywhere.  Fix that.

If you do see a banner, then it's likely sendmail's not binding to your external IP address.  Do a

```
netstat -an|grep -w 25|grep LISTEN
```

If you see the line

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

I'm wrong, and we must dig further.  If you see

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

then sendmail has been configured only to listen on the loopback interface, which is why you can't get to it from off the box.  Look for a line that says

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl
```

in your `sendmail.mc`, delete it (if you ignore me, and comment it out instead, use a `dnl` at the beginning of the line, not a `#`), regenerate your `sendmail.cf` and restart sendmail.

Comment: ...or maybe just not running?

Comment: Thanks! True enough, it's only configured to listen to localhost. I have disabled all the lines. It works!