# Postfix cant recieve mail from external source centos 7

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot, centos7, squirrelmail

I am using postfix, dovecot, squirrelmail for mail server everything is working fine except I can't receive mail from external source. I can send mails to local and external source.

I am following [this](http://www.unixmen.com/setup-a-local-mail-server-in-centos-7/) tutorial

I get this error on sending mail from external source

```
Technical details of temporary failure:
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720
[(1) mail.example.com. [62.210.36.xx]:25: socket error]
[(10) smtp.example.com. [62.210.36.xx]:25: socket error]
```

my postfix main.conf

```
myhostname = mail.example.com
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mynetworks = 62.210.36.0/24, 62.210.16.0/6, 192.168.1.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8, [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks_style = host
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

my dovecot config

```
dovecot.conf
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp 

10-mail.conf
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir

10-auth.conf
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
```

I have this on smtp port check

```
[root@example ~]# sudo netstat -pel | grep smtp
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      root       106803     19109/master
tcp6       0      0 localhost:smtp          [::]:*                  LISTEN      root       106804     19109/master
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     106845   19109/master         private/smtp
```

I have this on port 25 check

```
[root@example ~]# netstat -plnt |grep :25
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2505/master
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2505/master
```

I have this on MX check

```
[root@example ~]# dig mx example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-18.el7_1.5 <<>> mx example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48464
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                        IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.         3600    IN      MX      1 mail.example.com.
example.com.         3600    IN      MX      10 smtp.example.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.         3600    IN      NS      ns42.domaincontrol.com.
example.com.         3600    IN      NS      ns41.domaincontrol.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.example.com.    3600    IN      A       62.210.36.xx
smtp.example.com.    3600    IN      A       62.210.36.xx

;; Query time: 558 msec
;; SERVER: 62.210.16.xx#53(62.210.16.xx)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 25 16:08:41 CET 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 169
```

Please see why I am not able to get mail from external source.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP 25 closed even I allow everything in firewall, debian server running sendmail](http://serverfault.com/questions/207754/smtp-25-closed-even-i-allow-everything-in-firewall-debian-server-running-sendma)

Comment: Your mailserver is listening on localhost only: `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25 ` Therefore it's not reachable from the outside.

Comment: @etagenklo how can I change that

Comment: @MadHatter That's sendmail, not postfix.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I agree, but the problem is the same: the MTA's only listening on the loopback address. Maybe it's time for a canonical question with one answer for each MTA?

Answer (score 1):

```
[root@jersey ~]# telnet 62.21X.36.XX 25
Trying 62.21X.36.XX...
telnet: connect to address 62.21X.36.XX: No route to host
```

Contact your ISP (or VPS provider).

Looks like they are filtering your inbound traffic.

Comment: Can you try now

Comment: looks good now.